# "Source Not Found: You need to find class to view the source for the current call stack frame" as result when debugging project code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

While investigating issues in a .net solution, I am encountering problems as I am unable to do debug or do any action. This is causing issues with debugging, such as breakpoints hitting or setting them properly.
The issue is where Visual Studio isn't able to find any source classes of the solution and its projects. It loads them as external sources, and allows showing some classes during debugging but not the actual source code breakpoints or parameter values during the run.

The issue is shown as:
Source Not Found:
[image: Issue encountered]

This happens for example when it hits one of previously defined breakpoints on any possible class in any project in the solution. Where these get loaded under:

[image: External Sources under the Solution Explorer]

Amongst the tried options were (which all were unsuccessful, and why I am here searching for answers):

- Testing on another machine.

  - Not occurring on the other machine/machines.
- Removing the .vs folder within the solution.
- Re-clonning the project.
- Updating Visual Studio.
- Setting MSBuild project build output verbosity: **Diagnostic** output under Tools => Options => Project and Solutions => Build and Run.
- Disabling **Enable address-level debugging** under Tools => Options => Debugging.
- Enabling Just My Code** under Tools => Options => Debugging.

Ideally would be to have proper debugging capabilities and run without having this issue where it occurs that my project depends on external sources to run and being unable to properly debug.

Comment: Have you tried resetting Visual Studio options? There isn't much useful information in your question Please provide a reproducible example and steps. .

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT, the issue is, this is a legacy project, and I did not manage to replicate it in a separate solution. And extracting a replicable, reproducible example from a complex solution wouldn't be a simple task, if at all. 
Thank you for the suggestion, resetting the Visual Studio options using the installer did the trick, although the import export settings reset didn't manage to resolve the issue for some reason.
The issue I have now is that I want to understand which options might have caused the issue.
If you have some ideas to share on that, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to pinpoint the actual issue on what caused it. As it was most probably based on the actual issue, related to local development environment setup, and as  @Minxin YU -MSFT mentioned, resetting it would probably resolve it. Which it did. But it did not provide any information on what was the actual root cause.

There are multiple options of doing it, and here are some I tried:

1. Using the Repair functionality from the Visual Studio Installer
   [image: Repair - Visual Studio Installer]

   - Which will reset the whole environment.
2. Using the Tools ⇾ Import and Export Settings feature and resetting it from there.
   [image]
3. And using the Developer Command Prompt option

   devenv /ResetSettings

**The one that worked for me was, the first option.**

Comment: Glad to know reset option work for you. You could accept the answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the class which you are debugging, that its containing dll has it's latest coresponding pdb file.

Comment: All of them are present and loaded, the PDBs files for the DLLs of the solution, but it's loading them as external Sources, and sometimes it shows the code loaded from the PDBs, but not hitting any breakpoints.